# Programming languages with a Lisp-like syntax extension mechanism

Tags: lisp, extensibility, macros

I have only a limited knowledge of Lisp (trying to learn a bit in my free time) but as far as I understand Lisp macros allow to introduce new language constructs and syntax by describing them in Lisp itself. This means that a new construct can be added as a library, without changing the Lisp compiler / interpreter.

This approach is very different from that of other programming languages. E.g., if I wanted to extend Pascal with a new kind of loop or some particular idiom I would have to extend the syntax and semantics of the language and then implement that new feature in the compiler.

Are there other programming languages outside the Lisp family (i.e. apart from Common Lisp, Scheme, Clojure (?), Racket (?), etc) that offer a similar possibility to extend the language within the language itself?

**EDIT**

Please, avoid extended discussion and be specific in your answers. Instead of a long list of programming languages that can be extended in some way or another, I would like to understand from a conceptual point of view what is specific to Lisp macros as an extension mechanism, and which non-Lisp programming languages offer some concept that is close to them.

Comment: Lisp has another trick besides regular macros.  "Reader Macros" allow the parser syntax to be captured and extended at runtime, so even the basic token structure of the language is under control.

Comment: @ddyer: Thanks, I didn't know about that: another topic to be added to my reading list.

Comment: I'd wager Ruby metaprogramming can meet this.

Comment: your question is contradictory, first you ask for a list, then you ask for conceptual information, which is it???

Comment: I am asking for a list, but not a generic one (not just any programming language that can be extended in some way) because this would be too general. I would like to know of languages that can be extended in a way similar to Lisp (the extension is defined using the same language that it extends, not some kind of meta-language). The answers of Péter Török, Thomas Eding, SK-logic, and Mechanical snail seem to be the closest to what I had in mind. I still have to read through all the answer carefully though.

Answer (score 19):

Scala makes this possible too (in fact it was consciously designed to support the definition of new language constructs and even complete DSLs).

Apart from higher-order functions, lambdas and currying, which are common in functional languages, there are some special language features here to enable this*:

- no operators - everything is a function, but function names can include special characters like '+', '-' or ':'
- dots and braces can be omitted for single-parameter method calls, i.e. `a.and(b)` is equivalent to `a and b` in infix form
- for single-parameter function calls you may use curly brackets instead of normal braces - this (together with currying) allows you to write things like

  ```
  val file = new File("example.txt")

  withPrintWriter(file) {
    writer => writer.println("this line is a function call parameter")
  }
  ```

  where `withPrintWriter` is a plain method with two parameter lists, both containing a single parameter
- by-name parameters allow you to omit empty parameter list in lambdas, allowing you to write calls like `myAssert(() => x > 3)` in a shorter form as `myAssert(x > 3)`

The creation of an example DSL is discussed in detail in [Chapter 11. Domain-Specific Languages in Scala](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596155957/DomainSpecificLanguages.html) of the free book [*Programming Scala*](http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/).

*<sub>I don't mean these are unique to Scala, but at least they don't seem to be very common. I am not an expert in functional languages though.</sub>

Comment: +1: Interesting. Does this mean that in order to extend the syntax I can define new classes and that method signatures will provide the new syntax as a by-product?

Comment: @Giorgio, basically yes.

Comment: The links don't work anymore.

Answer (score 13):

### Haskell

Haskell has "Template Haskell" as well as "Quasiquotation":

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Template_Haskell

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Quasiquotation

These features allow users to dramatically add to the syntax of the language outside of normal means. These are resolved at compile time as well, which I think is a big must (for compiled languages at least) [1].

I have used quasiquotation in Haskell once before to create an advanced pattern matcher over a C-like language:

```
moveSegment :: [Token] -> Maybe (SegPath, SegPath, [Token])
moveSegment [hc| HC_Move_Segment(@s, @s); | s1 s2 ts |] = Just (mkPath s1, mkPath s2, ts)
moveSegment _ = Nothing
```

[1] Else the following qualifies as syntax extension: `runFeature "some complicated grammar enclosed in a string to be evaluated at runtime"`, which of course is a load of crap.

Comment: There are also other features of Haskell that essentially allow for custom syntax, like creating your own operator or the automatic currying coupled with lambda functions (consider e.g. the typical usage of `forM`).

Comment: I honestly think currying and custom operators do not qualify. They allow one to use the language neatly, but they don't allow you to add /new/ functionality to the language. TH and QQ do. In a strict sense, neither do TH and QQ in the sense that they do exactly what they are designed to do, but they allow you to really go "out of the language" at compile time.

Comment: "Else the following qualifies as syntax extension...": very good point.

Answer (score 13):

Perl allows for pre-processing of its language.  While this isn't often used to the extent of radically changing the syntax in the language, it can be seen in some of the... odd modules:

- [Acme::Bleach](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Acme-Bleach-1.150/lib/Acme/Bleach.pm) for really clean code
- [Acme::Morse](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Acme-Bleach-1.150/lib/Acme/Morse.pm) for writing in morse code
- [Lingua::Romana::Perligata](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Lingua-Romana-Perligata-0.50/lib/Lingua/Romana/Perligata.pm) for writing in Latin (for examples, nouns are variables and number, case, and declension change the type of the noun nextum ==> $next, nexta ==> @next)

There also exists a module that makes allows perl to run code that looks like it was written in Python.

A more modern approach to this within perl would be to use [Filter::Simple](http://perldoc.perl.org/Filter/Simple.html) (one of the core modules in perl5).

Note that all those examples involve Damian Conway who has been referred to as the "Mad Doctor of Perl".  Its still an amazingly powerful ability within perl to twist the language how one wants it.

More documentation for this and other alternatives exists at [perlfilter](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfilter.html).

Answer (score 12):

[Tcl](http://www.tcl.tk/) has a long history of supporting extensible syntax. For example, here's the implementation of a loop that iterates three variables (until stopped) over the cardinals, their squares and their cubes:

```
proc loopCard23 {cardinalVar squareVar cubeVar body} {
    upvar 1 $cardinalVar cardinal $squareVar square $cubeVar cube

    # We borrow a 'for' loop for the implementation...
    for {set cardinal 0} true {incr cardinal} {
        set square [expr {$cardinal ** 2}]
        set cube [expr {$cardinal ** 3}]

        uplevel 1 $body
    }
}
```

That would then be used like this:

```
loopCard23 a b c {
    puts "got triplet: $a, $b, $c"
    if {$c > 400} {
        break
    }
}
```

This sort of technique is used extensively in Tcl programming, and the key to doing it sanely are the `upvar` and `uplevel` commands (`upvar` binds a named variable in another scope to a local variable, and `uplevel` runs a script in another scope: in both cases, the `1` indicates that the scope in question is the caller's). It's also used a lot in code that couples with databases (running some code for each row in a result set), in Tk for GUIs (for doing binding of callbacks to events), etc.

However, that's only a fraction of what is done. The embedded language doesn't even need to be Tcl; it can be virtually anything (as long as it balances its braces — things get syntactically horrible if that's not true — which is the enormous majority of programs) and Tcl can just dispatch to the embedded foreign language as necessary. Examples of doing this include [embedding C to implement Tcl commands](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2523) and the equivalent with Fortran. (Arguably, all Tcl's built-in commands are done this way in a sense, in that they're really just a standard library and not the language itself.)

Answer (score 10):

This is partly a question of semantics. The basic idea of Lisp is that the program is data that can itself be manipulated. Commonly-used languages in the Lisp family, like Scheme, don't really let you add new *syntax* in the parser sense; it's all just space-delimited parenthesized lists. It's just that since the core syntax does so little, you can make almost any *semantic* construct out of it. Scala (discussed below) is similar: the variable-name rules are so liberal that you can easily make nice DSLs out of it (while staying within the same core syntax rules).

These languages, while they don't actually let you define new syntax in the sense of Perl filters, have a sufficiently flexible core that you can use it to build DSLs and add language constructs.

The important common feature is that they let you define language constructs that work as well as built-in ones, using features exposed by the languages. The degree of support for this feature varies:

- Many older languages provided built-in functions like `sin()`, `round()`, etc., without any way to implement your own.
- C++ provides limited support. For example some built-in keywords like casts (`static_cast<target_type>(input)`, `dynamic_cast<>()`, `const_cast<>()`, `reinterpret_cast<>()`) can be emulated using template functions, which Boost uses for `lexical_cast<>()`, `polymorphic_cast<>()`, `any_cast<>()`, ....
- Java has built-in control structures (`for(;;){}`, `while(){}`, `if(){}else{}`, `do{}while()`, `synchronized(){}`, `strictfp{}`) and doesn't let you define your own. Scala instead defines an abstract syntax that lets you call functions using a convenient control-structure-like syntax, and libraries use this to effectively define new control structures (e.g. `react{}` in the actors library).

---

Also, you might look at Mathematica's custom syntax functionality in the [Notation package](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Notation/guide/NotationPackage.html). (Technically it is in the Lisp family, but has some extensibility features done differently, as well as the usual Lisp extensibility.)

Comment: Wrong. Lisp *does* actually allow you to add absolutely any kind of a new syntax. Like in this example: http://www.meta-alternative.net/pfront.pdf - it is nothing but a Lisp macro.

Comment: That seems to be implemented in [a language specifically designed for building DSLs](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/2895). Of course you can make a language in the Lisp family that also provides such features; I meant that that feature isn't a core Lisp idea supported bcommonly-used Lisps (e.g. Scheme). Edited to clarify.

Comment: This "language for building DSLs" is a collection of macros built on top of a pretty typical, minimalistic Lisp. It can be easily ported to any other Lisp with `(defmacro ...)`. Actually I'm currently porting this language to Racket, just for fun. But, I agree that it is something not very useful, since S-expressions syntax is more than enough for most of the possible useful semantic s.

Comment: And, Scheme is not any different from Common Lisp, starting from R6RS officially, and unofficially for ages, since it does provide a `(define-macro ...)` equivalent, which, in turn, can use any kind of parsing internally.

Answer (score 8):

[Rebol](http://www.rebol.com) sounds almost like what you're describing, but a bit sideways.

Rather than define specific syntax, everything in Rebol is a function call - there are no keywords. (Yes, you can redefine `if` and `while` if you truly desire to).  For example, this is an `if` statement:

```
if now/time < 12:00 [print "Morning"]
```

`if` is a function that takes 2 arguments:  a condition and a block.  If the condition is true, the block is evaluated.  Sounds like most languages, right?  Well, the block is a data structure, it's not restricted to code - this is a block of blocks, for example, and a quick example of the flexibility of "code is data":

```
SomeArray: [ [foo "One"] [bar "Two"] [baz "Three"] ]
foreach action SomeArray [action/1: 'print] ; Change the data
if now/time < 12:00 SomeArray/2 ; Use the data as code - right now, if now/time < 12:00 [print "Two"]
```

As long as you can stick to the syntax rules, extending this language is, for the most part, going to be nothing more than defining new functions.  Some users have been backporting features of Rebol 3 into Rebol 2, for example.

Answer (score 7):

Ruby has a quite flexible syntax, I think it's a way of "extend the language within the language itself".

An example is [rake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rake_%28software%29). It's written in Ruby, it is Ruby, but it looks like [make](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29).

To check some possibilities you can look for the keywords *Ruby* and *metaprogramming*.

Comment: "flexible syntax" is VERY different from "extensible syntax". It's been a long while since I've programmed in Ruby, but Rake just looks like a well designed use of built-in syntax. In other words, this is a non-example.

Comment: Isn't that a matter of degree, not of kind?  How would you distinguish between an "extensible syntax" language that can extend some aspects of its syntax but not others, and a "flexible syntax" language?

Comment: If the line is blurry, then let's push back the line so that C is considered to support extensible syntax.

Comment: To link with your example, I'd draw the line here: A language with extensible syntax can make rake, which looks like make. A language with flexible syntax can be extended (ha, nice linguistic blending there) to compile and run makefiles. Your point on matter of degree is a good one though. Maybe some languages allow for compiling Make, but not Python. And others would allow for both.

Comment: Any turing complete language should be able to be made to process Make files. Flexibility of syntax isn't a factor beyond how much a challenge it would be.

Comment: @Rig The question is, whether you can have the programming language accept the make file as valid syntax that describes an actual program in said language.

Comment: @phant0m Ah I see. I get it now.

Answer (score 7):

Extending the syntax the way you're talking about allows you to create [domain specific languages.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321712943)  So perhaps the most useful way to rephrase your question is, what other languages have good support for domain specific languages?

Ruby has very flexible syntax, and a lot of DSLs have flourished there, such as rake.  Groovy includes a lot of that goodness.  It also includes AST transforms, which are more directly analogous to Lisp macros.

R, the language for statistical computing, allows functions to get their arguments unevaluated.  It uses this to create a DSL for specifying regression formula.  For example:

```
y ~ a + b
```

means "fit a line of the form k0 + k1*a + k2*b to the values in y."

```
y ~ a * b
```

means "fit a line of the form k0 + k1*a + k2*b + k3*a*b to the values in y."

And so on.

Comment: Groovy's AST transforms are very verbose compared to Lisp or Clojure macros. For example the 20+ line Groovy example at http://groovy.codehaus.org/Global+AST+Transformations could be rewritten as one short line in Clojure, e.g. `(this (println ~message)). Not only that but you also wouldn't have to compile the jar, write the metadata, or any of the other stuff on that Groovy page.

Answer (score 7):

[Converge](http://convergepl.org/documentation/current/ctmp/) is another one non-lispy metaprogramming language. And, to some extent, C++ qualifies too.

Arguably, [MetaOCaml](http://www.metaocaml.org/) is quite far from Lisp. For a totally different style of syntax extensibility, but yet quite powerful, take a look at [CamlP4](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-camlp4/index.html).

[Nemerle](http://nemerle.org/About/) is another extensible language with a Lisp-style metaprogramming, although it is closer to languages like Scala.

And, Scala itself [will soon become](http://scalamacros.org/) such a language too.

Edit: I forgot about the most interesting example - [JetBrains MPS](http://www.jetbrains.com/mps/). It is not only very distant from anything Lispish, it is even a non-textual programming system, with an editor operating directly on an AST level.

Edit2: To answer an updated question - there is nothing unique and exceptional in the Lisp macros. In theory, any language can provide such a mechanism (I even did it with plain C). All you need is an access to your AST and an ability to execute code in compilation time. Some reflection might help (querying about the types, the existing definitions, etc.).

Comment: Your Scala link explicitly says that the proposed macros "cannot change syntax of Scala". (Interesting, it lists this as a difference between that proposal and C/C++ preprocessor macros!)

Comment: @ruakh, yes, it is the same approach as Converge and Template Haskell - macro application is explicitly marked and cannot be mixed with a "normal" syntax. But, inside you can have any syntax you like, so arguably it is an extensible syntax. The "non-lisp" requirement, unfortunately, limits your options to languages like this.

Comment: "I even did it with plain C": How is this possible?

Comment: @Giorgio, of course I've modified a compiler (added macros and an incremental module compilation, which is actually quite natural for C).

Comment: Why is access to the AST necessary?

Comment: @RenéG, because macros must be able to *construct* a valid AST and to transform an AST (i.e., be able to deconstruct macro arguments).

Answer (score 6):

Prolog allows defining new operators which are translated to compound terms of the same name. For example, this defines a `has_cat` operator and defines it as a predicate for checking if a list contains the atom `cat`:

```
:- op(500, xf, has_cat).
X has_cat :- member(cat, X).

?- [apple, cat, orange] has_cat.
true ;
false.
```

The `xf` means that `has_cat` is a postfix operator; using `fx` would make it a prefix operator, and `xfx` would make it an infix operator, taking two arguments. Check [this link](http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/learn-prolog-now/html/node84.html) for more details about defining operators in Prolog.

Answer (score 5):

[Boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/) lets you customize the language heavily at compile-time through syntactic macros.

Boo has an "extensible compiler pipeline". That means the compiler can call your code to do AST transformations at any point during the compiler pipeline. As you know, things like Java's Generics or C#'s Linq are just syntax transformations at compile time, so this is *quite* powerful.

Compared to Lisp, the main advantage is that this works with any kind of syntax. Boo is using a Python-inspired syntax, but you could probably write an extensible compiler with a C or Pascal syntax. And since the macro is evaluated at compile time, there's no performance penalty.

Downsides, compared to Lisp, are:

- Working with an AST is not as elegant as working with s-expressions
- Since the macro is invoked at compile time, it doesn't have access to runtime data.

For example, this is how you might implement a new control structure:

```
macro repeatLines(repeatCount as int, lines as string*):
    for line in lines:
        yield [| print $line * $repeatCount |]
```

usage:

```
repeatLines 2, "foo", "bar"
```

which then gets translated, at compile time, to something like:

```
print "foo" * 2
print "bar" * 2
```

(Unfortunately, Boo's online documentation is always hopelessly outdated and doesn't even cover advanced stuff like this. The best documentation for the language I know is this book: http://www.manning.com/rahien/)

Comment: The web documentation for this feature is currently broken, and I don't write Boo myself, but I thought it would be a pity if it was overlooked. I appreciate the mod feedback and will reconsider how I go about contributing free information in my spare time.

Answer (score 5):

The evaluation [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) is based on pattern matching and replacement. That allows you to create your own control structures, change existing control structures or change the way expressions are evaluated. For example, you could implement "fuzzy logic" like this (a bit simplified):

```
fuzzy[a_ && b_]      := Min[fuzzy[a], fuzzy[b]]
fuzzy[a_ || b_]      := Max[fuzzy[a], fuzzy[b]]
fuzzy[!a_]           := 1-fuzzy[a]
If[fuzzy[a_], b_,c_] := fuzzy[a] * fuzzy[b] + fuzzy[!a] * fuzzy[c]
```

This overrides the evaluation for the predefined logical operators &&,||,! and the built-in `If` clause.

You can read these definitions like function definitions, but the real meaning is: If an expression matches the pattern described on the left side, it's replaced with the expression on the right side. You could define your own If-clause like this:

```
myIf[True, then_, else_] := then
myIf[False, then_, else_] := else
SetAttributes[myIf, HoldRest]
```

`SetAttributes[..., HoldRest]` tells the evaluator that it should evaluate the first argument before the pattern matching, but hold evaluation for the rest until after the pattern has been matched and replaced.

This is used extensively inside the Mathematica standard libraries to e.g. define a function `D` that takes an expression and evaluates to its symbolic derivative.

Answer (score 5):

**TeX** is totally missing from the list. You all know it, right? It looks something like this:

```
Some {\it ``interesting''} example.
```

… except that you can redefine the syntax without restrictions. Every (!) token in the language can be assigned a new meaning. *ConTeXt* is a macro package which has replaced curly braces with square braces:

```
Some \it[``interesting''] example.
```

The more common macro package *LaTeX* also redefines the language for its purposes, e.g. adding the `\begin{environment}…\end{environment}` syntax.

But it doesn’t stop there. Technically, you could just as well redefine the tokens to parse the following:

```
Some <it>“interesting”</it> example.
```

Yes, absolutely possible. Some packages use this to define small domain-specific languages. For instance, the *TikZ* package defines a concise syntax for technical drawings, which allows the following:

```
\foreach \angle in {0, 30, ..., 330} 
  \draw[line width=1pt] (\angle:0.82cm) -- (\angle:1cm);
```

Furthermore, TeX is Turing complete so you can literally do *everything* with it. I have never seen this used to its full potential because it would be pretty pointless and very convoluted but it’s entirely possible to make the following code parseable just by redefining tokens (but this would probably go to the physical limits of the parser, due to the way it’s built):

```
for word in [Some interesting example.]:
    if word == interesting:
        it(word)
    else:
        word
```

Answer (score 3):

**[Metalua](http://metalua.luaforge.net/)** is a language and a compiler compatible with Lua that provides this.

> - Full compatibility with Lua 5.1 sources and bytecode: clean, elegant    semantics and syntax, amazing expressive power, good
>     performances,    near-universal portability.
>     **-  A complete macro system, similar in power to what's offfered by Lisp dialects or Template Haskell; manipulated programs can be seen
>
>     as source code, as abstract syntax trees, or as an arbitrary mix
>
>     thereof, whichever suits your task better.**
> - A dynamically extensible parser, which lets you support your macros with a syntax that blends nicely with the rest of the    language.
> - A set of language extensions, all implemented as regular metalua macros.

Differences with Lisp:

> - Don't bother developers with macros when they aren't writing one: **the language's syntax and semantics should be best suited for those
>     95% of the time when we aren't writing macros.**
> - Encourage developers to follow the conventions of the language: not only with "best practices rants" nobody listen to, but by offering
>     an API that makes it easier to write things the Metalua Way.
>     Readability by fellow developers is more important and more difficult
>     to achieve than readability by compilers, and for this, having a
>     common set of respected conventions helps a lot.
> - Yet provide all the power one's willing to handle. Neither Lua nor Metalua are into mandatory bondage and discipline, so if you know what
>     you're doing, the language won't get in your way.
> - **Make it obvious when something interesting happens: all meta-operations happen between +{...} and -{...}, and visually stick
>     out of the regular code.**

An exemple of application is the implementation of ML-like pattern matching.

See also : http://lua-users.org/wiki/MetaLua

Comment: Although Lua is not a Lisp indeed, your list of "differences" is quite suspicious (the only relevant item is the last one). And, of course, Lisp community would not agree with a rant that one should not be writing/using macros 95% of the time - Lisp way leans towards something like 95% of the time using and writing DSLs, on top of macros, of course.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for languages that are extendable, you ought to take a look at Smalltalk.

In Smalltalk, the **only way** to program is to actually extend the language. There is no difference between the IDE, the libraries or the language itself. They're all so entwined that Smalltalk is often referred to as an environment rather than as a language.

You don't write stand-alone applications in Smalltalk, you extend the language-environment instead.

Check out http://www.world.st/ for a handful of resources and information.

I'd like to recommend Pharo as the dialect of entry to the world of Smalltalk: http://pharo-project.org

Hope it helped!

Comment: Sounds interesting.

Answer (score 1):

There are tools that allow making custom languages without writing a whole compiler from scratch. For example there is [Spoofax](http://strategoxt.org/Spoofax), which is a code transformation tool: you put in input grammar and transformation rules (written in a very high level declarative way), and then you can generate Java source code (or other language, if you care enough) from a custom language designed by you.

So, it would be possible to take grammar of language X, define grammar of language X' (X with your custom extensions) and transformation X'→X, and Spoofax will generate a compiler X'→X.

Currently, if I understand correctly, the best support is for Java, with C# support being developed (or so I heard). This technique could be applied to any language with static grammar (so, e.g. [probably not Perl](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=663393)) though.

Answer (score 1):

[Forth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29) is another language that is highly extensible.  Many Forth implementations consist of a small kernel written in assembler or C, then the rest of the language is written in Forth itself.

There are also several stack-based languages that are inspired by Forth and share this feature, such as [Factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_%28programming_language%29).

Answer (score 0):

### Funge-98

Funge-98's fingerprint feature allows could be done to allow a complete restructuring of the entire syntax and semantics of the language. But only if the implementor supplies a fingerprint mechanism that allowed the user to programmatically alter the langauage (this is theoretically possible to implement within normal Funge-98 syntax and semantics). If so, one could literally make the rest of the file (or whatever parts of the file) act as C++ or Lisp (or whatever he wants).

http://quadium.net/funge/spec98.html#Fingerprints

Comment: why did you post this separately instead of adding into [your previous answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/164667/31260)?

Comment: Because Funge has nothing to do with Haskell.

Answer (score -1):

To get what you're looking for you really need those parentheses and a lack of syntax. A few syntax-based languages may come close, but it is not quite the same thing as a true macro.